# How can I make an animation correlate to the current position of a UIImageView?

Tags: ios, animation, methods, uiimageview

I have an ImageView that changes between 2 different images. When an event happens and it's in ImageView1, I want it to play a specific animation. And when an event happens and it's in ImageView2, I want it to play a specific, different animation. My code set up so far is essentially

```
if (ImageView1 == YES)
{
ImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageAnimate1.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageAnimate2.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageAnimate3.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageAnimate4.png"], nil];
    [ImageView setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
    ImageView.animationDuration = 1;
    [ImageView startAnimating];
}

else
{
    ImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageAnimate5.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageAnimate6.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageAnimate7.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageAnimate8.png"], nil];
    [ImageView setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
    ImageView.animationDuration = 1;
    [ImageView startAnimating];
}
```

I'm aware it doesn't need to have 2 different sets of animation repeats and duration, but that was just the beginning in the event they change later.

The main problem is, the first set of animations only plays if i'm currently setting it to ImageView1. What I mean is, If i'm tapping/ touching the screen to the left it creates ImageView1, and if i'm tapping to the right it creates ImageView2. How can I change it from having to currently be tapping to the left to play that animation, to just playing the animation when the ImageView is currently displayed as such?

It might be as simple as setting it to the current UIImage, but i'm not exactly sure how to do it.

In other words, I would want to somehow write.

```
if (UIImage ImageViewLeft = YES)
    ImageView.animationImages etc etc etc.

else ImageView.animationImages would be the second variation.
```

EDIT: I just changed it to

```
 if (ImageView.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageLeft.png"])
     { code here
```

What happens is though now i cant change direction until another event happens. Essentially it will be stuck in either left or right until the event happens and then it correlates to the correct image then. .

Answer (score -1):

A simple way would be to create a BOOL for imageIsRight. You set it to YES when you start playing an animation on the right, you set it to NO, when it goes left. Then create a timer which fires every .05 seconds (or whatever works). That timer can call a method which checks the BOOL you created and either repeats/continues the current animation or stops it and starts the other.

The above details may not be perfect for your scenario, which is a bit fuzzy to me, but the approach should get you where you need to be.

Comment: I already have a boolean for it. Sorry for not being as specific as I could be.

It's essentially a BOOL for left and right. the left will set it equal to left if something happens, and right if the other statement happens earlier in the code. It's kinda shown already in this code though.

Comment: And how about a timer on a loop to detect the bool and play or switch the animation? Did you try that...I bet it will complete what you need.